# How to check if a cmdlet exists in PowerShell at runtime via script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script that needs to run under multiple hosts (PowerGUI, [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), etc...), but I am having an issue where sometimes a cmdlet doesn't exist under one of the hosts. Is there a way to check to see if a cmdlet exists so that I can wrap the code in an if block and do something else when it does not exist?

I know I could use the `$host.name` to section the code that is suppose to run on each host, but I would prefer to use [Feature Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(VS.85).aspx#DetectFtr) instead in case the cmdlet ever gets added in the future.

I also could use a try/catch block, but since it runs in managed code I assume there is away to detect if a cmdlet is installed via code.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Use the `Get-Command` cmdlet to test for the existence of a cmdlet:

```
if (Get-Command $cmdName -errorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    "$cmdName exists"
}
```

And if you want to ensure it is a cmdlet (and not an exe or function or script) use the `-CommandType` parameter e.g `-CommandType Cmdlet`

Comment: Didn't know there was an errorAction parameter. Found the list of all Common Parameters here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901844(VS.85).aspx which is good to know. Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: you can also check for Modules using `if (get-module | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ServerManager"}) { "Module Exists" }`. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027156/how-to-import-system-modules-automatically

Comment: cmdlet may exist, but not be available. Good example: Get-WinEvent exists on Windows 2003, but it throws NotImplemented exception. How would you handle this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way to handle this for an arbitrary cmdlet. If you're only testing Get-WinEvent, you would know appropriate parameters to pass and wrap with a try/catch.  I don't think that's feasible for an arbitrary cmdlet.  That said, I think it is a corner-case for a cmdlet to throw a NotImplementedException- at least I hope so.  :-(

Comment: @Neolisk can't you try `$test = Get-WinEvent -LogName system -MaxEvents 1; [bool]$test` and if it returns False then the cmdlet is not available?

Answer (score 34):

This is a simple function to do what you're like to do :)

```
function Check-Command($cmdname)
{
    return [bool](Get-Command -Name $cmdname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}
```

How to use (for example):

```
if (Check-Command -cmdname 'Invoke-WebRequest')
{
     Invoke-WebRequest $link -OutFile $destination
}
else
{
     $webclient.DownloadFile($link, $destination)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the command is in Verb-Noun form then you can use Get-Command with Verb and Noun parameters.

```bsh
# Usage:
if (Get-Command -Verb Invoke -Noun MyCommand) {
  # cmdlet Invoke-MyCommand exists
}
```

---

```bsh
Get-Command -Verb Get -Noun Item

# Output:
# CommandType     Name                  Version    Source
# -----------     ----                  -------    ------
# Cmdlet          Get-Item              7.0.0.0    #Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

```bsh
Get-Command -Verb Take -Noun One

# No output.
```

```bsh
function Take-One { [CmdletBinding()]param() }
Get-Command -Verb Take -Noun One

# Output:
# CommandType     Name                   Version    Source
# -----------     ----                   -------    ------
# Function        Take-One
```

Tested on Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 7.0.

**Edit 2020-11-09** Additional example. Also usage example (adapted from Keith Hill answer).

Comment: I know this question is very old. Just a memo for my future self.