# How to Import system modules automatically?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using Windows 2008 r2 64 bit system.

While testing our script ,we did right click on powershell (which is present in taskbar) and import system modules.

Our scripts will be used while deployment. So in destination machine we are not sure whether all system modules are imported or not?

How to make import all the system modules imported if not imported already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a hidden powershell switch to load system modules:

```
powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules
```

System modules reside in the $pshome\modules folder. The equivalent command to load them would be:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "$PSHOME*"} | Import-Module
```

UPDATE:

The -ImportSystemModules switch has no impact in v3, looks like it is going away.

Comment: I was wondering how the taskbar thing was done, but lacking documentation this is probably nothing to rely on.

Comment: @joey did you mean the green progress bar ?

Comment: No, just the »Import system modules«. I don't really know how to find the actual command lines associated with the tasks in the right-click menu on a taskbar item. I know what Write-Progress is ;)

Comment: I just copied the modules to $pshome\modules and the next time I opened the powershell the module was loaded automatically