# What is the purpose of ImportSystemModules?

Tags: powershell

What is the purpose of ImportSystemModules? Using `help ImportSystemModules -Full` produces an empty shell description.

```
PS 09:12  C:\src
>get-command *module*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Find-Module                                        2.2.1      PowerShellGet
Function        Get-InstalledModule                                2.2.1      PowerShellGet
Function        **ImportSystemModules**
Function        InModuleScope                                      3.4.0      Pester
Function        Install-Module                                     2.2.1      PowerShellGet
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Roger Lipscombe's blog](http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2012/01/05/powershell-importsystemmodules/), it used to do the following:

> This runs `Powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules`, which, in turn, runs the `ImportSystemModules` command. You can call this command as part of your profile, if you want these modules loaded each time you run PowerShell.
>
> Various places on the Internet state that it loads the available modules from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. Among these are modules for managing IIS, Hyper-V, etc.
>
> It turns out that it also loads snap-ins from `C:\Users\rogerl\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Snapins`

However, according to [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052721/584676):

> The `-ImportSystemModules` switch has no impact in v3, looks like it is going away.

And the [Powershell changelog states for v6 beta 9](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7f01d1ca6c5a996a4e73f513b9fad4a1d7544c06/CHANGELOG.md#v600-beta9---2017-10-24) states the argument has been removed entirely:

> Remove parameters `-importsystemmodules` and `-psconsoleFile` from powershell.exe. (#4995)

And indeed, running `Get-Command ImportSystemModules` on Powershell Core v6 cannot find the command anymore:

```
> Get-Command ImportSystemModules
Get-Command : The term 'ImportSystemModules' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

As to why it's still there and defined in v5.1 and earlier? Perhaps it's for backwards compatibility, v2 compatibility was guaranteed for a long time.