# How to check if a command is available in a Windows shell?

Tags: shell, command

To check if a command is available in a bash shell, I usually do:

```
command -v $COMMAND >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
    echo >&2 "Error: this script requires the command '$COMMAND' to be available"
    exit 1
}
```

What is the equivalent in Windows?

Comment: Do you mean PowerShell or command prompt?

Comment: Command prompt :-) But if you post an answer for power shell, I'll +1 just because I'll learn something.

Comment: For Powershell

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919798/how-to-check-if-a-cmdlet-exists-in-powershell-at-runtime-via-script

Comment: Do you mean to check bash command (e.g.: mingw bash) or CMD command?

Comment: A cmd command. With bash I would use the same snippet.

Comment: The only way I see you could do the same thing would be to `cd` to the directory you think it exists and check if the file exists using `IF exists filename`.

Comment: It's not that a bad idea. I could iterate on the system PATH and check if the command exists in any directory

Comment: I have a JScript script that I use for this - it's "which", basically, but it works as a test, too, since it doesn't output anything if the command doesn't exist.  Don't forget to iterate over all the possible executable suffixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something very similar

```
%command% >nul 2>&1 || (
    echo "Error: command not found"
    exit /b 1
)
```

Granted, this will actually execute the command, but most commands will do nothing without proper parameters. If you want to be more sure, you can use `%command% /? >nul 2&1`. This will try to bring the help page for the command, without executing it

**Update:**
To avoid executing the command entirely, consider `where.exe`. It comes bundled with Vista and Windows 7. For other OSes, you can download it. Please refer to [this post on how to download it](https://superuser.com/questions/249725/where-to-download-where-exe-tool-for-windows-xp)

Once you have it, you can run it with `/Q` switch to avoid extra output. Return code of 0 means command was found. Once thing that I found is that the `where` command requires you to supply the extension.

One the other end, there is a [lengthy discussion here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/20/357225.aspx) about a batch "one-liner" that works without an extension specified (but actually fails when you do specify an extension)

Comment: It's an interesting alternative. Not always wanted, but still, can be useful.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include alternatives that don't execute the command you are testing for